# Can Facebook send a confirmation code to an alternate email not associated with my account?

Tags: facebook

I forgot my Facebook password and couldn't remember my email address so I created a new email address. Can Facebook send me a confirmation code so I can reset my password and log in to Facebook?

Comment: You don't remember your email either? Or just the password to the email?

Comment: I really doubt it. How are you going to prove you are who you say you are? _I_ could use the same tool to say I'm you. Your only options are those that can be found at [Facebook Help: I can't reset my password because I can't access the email address listed on my account](https://www.facebook.com/help/132243923516844)

Answer (score 1):

No, if they did that, that'd be just a super easy way for *anyone* to take over an account.

Comment: So what can I do? I'm not gonna create a new Facebook account because I have too many pictures, etc.I created a new gmail address & a new password for my new gmail, now I need to know how to use my new gmail as my Facebook gmail & how to reset my Facebook password.. I've been on Facebook help for the past 5 days & I'm not getting anywhere I'm aggravated. Please help me!!!

Comment: @KimberlyHarrison you can try these steps. https://www.facebook.com/help/132243923516844 Beyond that, I'm afraid there's nothing you can do

Answer (score -1):

You can try to send message to Facebook and ask if they could send you code to other email or do something else. And there is many smart guys who could help also. RTry to contact to facebook and if you canät solve your problem so I can recommend one guy who helped me with one account problem. His name was Vadim and email was cravadi [at] yandex.com. Hope you will got your problem solved :/